# Sun tracker Stepper Motor Simulation using pic16f877a

Tags: c, pic, mikroc

I have written a code for dual axis sun tracking based on time..
I am interfacing an lcd with the pic 16f877a.
I have stumbled on a problem.
The problem I find here is that if I write it as `int am1` I get output as 1.0 (I want the output to show 1.8). Here 1.8 is the step angle of the motor.
If I write it as `double am1` I get an error saying operator not applicable to this operands.
If I write it as `long am1` it does not rotate properly, i.e it turns 1.8 degrees and then 3.6* in the opposite direction (Considering Step Angle is 1.8*)

I've got another problem also.
I have put 2 `while` loops in the beginning, `while(count2>13)` and `while(count2<13)`, if  certain conditions are not satisfied.
Now after the while loops it should go to the infinite loop but after the first 2 `for` loops in the infinite loop it seems to start from the beginning, i.e. the `while` loop
Just see what is the problem.
I noticed something:
If I remove the 2nd `while` loop, i.e. `while(count2<13)` the program seems to work properly and vice versa. If 1st `while` loop is removed and 2nd kept it works properly.
Now, I don't know what's causing the previous problem to occur.

```
int i;
int j;
int k;
int m;
int l;

int ch;
int count=0;          //Keep track of days
int count1=0;         //Reference position of motor
int count2=13+2;      //Equator count value+(days passed since equator/7)
int count3=0;
int count4=0;         //Direction of N-S motor  0=clockwise   1=anticlockwise
int count5=0;
int count6=0;
int count7=0;
int count8=13;       //Count at equator
int am1=0.0;
int am2=0.0;
char txt1[6];
//LCD Module Connection Initialization
sbit LCD_RS at RC2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RC3_bit;

sbit LCD_D7 at RC7_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RC6_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RC4_bit;
//End of LCD Module Connection

//Intialization of LCD Pin Direction
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISC2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISC3_bit;

sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISC7_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISC6_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISC4_bit;
//End of LCD Pin Direction

void main()
{ 
  //Intialization of Ports
  TRISB=0X00;     //Initialize Port B as output
  PORTB=0X00;     //Assign Value 0 to port B
  TRISD=0X00;     //Initialize Port D as output
  PORTD=0X00;     //Assign Value 0 to port D
  //End of Initialization

  Lcd_Init();                     //Initailize LCD Module
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);            //Clear Display
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);       //Cursor Off
  while(count2>13){               //If Earth greater than 0* of the Equator
    PORTD=0X04;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
    delay_ms(500);                //Short delay
    count8++;                     //Increment value to increment motor value by 1
    if(count8==count2){           //Check if motor value = Equinox value
      PORTD=0X00;                   //Pass no current to motor
      count1=1;                     //Reference position value set
      delay_ms(500);                //Short delay
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X02;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
    delay_ms(500);                //Short delay
    count8++;                     //Increment value to increment motor value by 1
    if(count8==count2){           //Check if motor value = Equinox value
      PORTD=0X00;                 //Pass no current to motor
      count1=2;                   //Reference position value set
      delay_ms(500);              //Short delay
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X08;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
    delay_ms(500);                //Short delay
    count8++;                     //Increment value to increment motor value by 1
    if(count8==count2){           //Check if motor value = Equinox value
      PORTD=0X00;                 //Pass no current to motor
      count1=3;                   //Reference position value set
      delay_ms(500);              //Short delay
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X01;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
    delay_ms(500);                //Short delay
    count8++;                     //Increment value to increment motor value by 1
    if(count8==count2){           //Check if motor value = Equinox value
      PORTD=0X00;                 //Pass no current to motor
      count1=0;                   //Reference position value set
      delay_ms(500);              //Short delay
      break;
    }
  }

  while(count2<13){      //If Earth lesser than 0* of the Equator
    PORTD=0X08;
    delay_ms(500);
    count8--;
    if(count8==count2){
      PORTD=0X00;
      count1=1;
      delay_ms(500);
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X02;
    delay_ms(500);
    count8--;
    if(count8==count2){
      PORTD=0X00;
      count1=2;
      delay_ms(500);
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X04;
    delay_ms(500);
    count8--;
    if(count8==count2){
      PORTD=0X00;
      count1=3;
      delay_ms(500);
      break;
    }
    PORTD=0X01;
    delay_ms(500);
    count8--;
    if(count8==count2){
      PORTD=0X00;
      count1=0;
      delay_ms(500);
      break;
    }
  }
  for(;;)                           //Infinite Loop
  {
    for(i=0;i<1;i++)                //Rotating from east to west by 1.8 every 7 minutes
    {
      PORTB=0X04;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      PORTB=0X00;                   //Pass no current to motor
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Angle M1:");
      am1=am1+1.8;
      Lcd_Chr(1,10,48+am1);         //Output value of am1 on LCD
      Lcd_Chr_CP('.');              //To display value "."
      ch=am1*10;
      ch=ch%10;
      Lcd_Chr(1,10,48+ch);

      PORTB=0X02;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      PORTB=0X00;                   //Pass no current to motor
      am1=am1+1.8;

      PORTB=0X08;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      PORTB=0X00;                   //Pass no current to motor
      am1=am1+1.8;

      PORTB=0X01;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      PORTB=0X00;                   //Pass no current to motor
      am1=am1+1.8;
    }
    for(j=0;j<1;j++)              //Rotating from west to east
    {
      PORTB=0X08;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      am1=am1-1.8;
      PORTB=0X02;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      am1=am1-1.8;
      PORTB=0X04;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      am1=am1-1.8;
      PORTB=0X01;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
      delay_ms(500);                //Delay
      am1=am1-1.8;
      count++;
    }
    if(count==2){                 //For 7 days ((365/94)=3.80) --> (1.8*3.80 = 6.84 = 7 days)
      if(count4==0){                //Reference that motor moving in clockwise  direction
        switch(count1){               //Reference position the motor stopped
          case 0:
            {
              if (count2==26){             //One end of Equinox = 23.5* --> For 47 degrees  ((47/1.8) = 26.11) =26 steps
                count4=1;                     //Reference that motor should move in anti-clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X04;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              count1=1;                     //Reference position value set
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2++;              //Increment Equinox Step by 1
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            {
              if (count2==26){             //One end of Equinox = 23.5*
                count4=1;                     //Reference that motor should move in anti-clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X02;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=2;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2++;              //Increment Equinox Step by 1
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            {
              if (count2==26){             //One end of Equinox = 23.5*
                count4=1;                     //Reference that motor should move in anti-clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X08;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=3;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2++;              //Increment Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
          case 3:
            {
              if (count2==26){             //One end of Equinox = 23.5*
                count4=1;                     //Reference that motor should move in anti-clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X01;               //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=0;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2++;              //Increment Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
        }
      }
      if(count4==1){                        //Reference that motor should move in anti-clockwise direction
        switch(count5){
          case 0:
            {
              if (count2==0){               //One end of Equinox = 23.5*
                count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              switch(count1){              //Reference position of the motor
                case 0:
                  {
                    count6=1;
                    break;
                  }
                case 1:
                  {
                    count6=4;
                    break;
                  }
                case 2:
                  {
                    count6=3;
                    break;
                  }
                case 3:
                  {
                    count6=2;
                    break;
                  }
              }
            }
        }
        switch(count6){
          case 1:
            {
              if (count2==0){               //One end of Equinox = 0.0*
                count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X08;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              count1=3;                     //Reference position value set
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2-1;              //Decrement Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
          case 2:
            {
              if (count2==0){              //One end of Equinox = 0.0*
                count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X02;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=2;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2-1;              //Decrement Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
          case 3:
            {
              if (count2==0){              //One end of Equinox = 0.0*
                count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X04;                   //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=1;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2-1;              //Decrement Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
          case 4:
            {
              if (count2==0){              //One end of Equinox = 0.0*
                count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
                break;
              }
              PORTD=0X01;               //Move stepper motor by a step
              count1=0;                     //Reference position value set
              count=0;                      //Reset 7 day counter to 0
              delay_ms(500);                //delay
              count2=count2-1;              //Decrement Equinox Step by 1
              break;
            }
        }
      }
      if (count2==0){                       //One end of Equinox = 0.0*
        count4=0;                     //Reference that motor should move in clockwise direction
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (l=0;l<2;l++){                   //Delay for the rest of the 12 hours
        delay_ms(431);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is almost impossible to read. Indent it properly, and give names to the counters that actually say what the counters are supposed to count. Then maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`am1` and `am2` are of type `int`. These variables are holding integer values. So by assigning float values, they will be casted to integers. So if you for example use

`am1 = 1.8;` the actual value of `am1` will be 1.

Comment: Without any offense, you need to carefully study some basic thinks in programming. I don't think that anyone here will debug your code for you. Ok you changed to float the variables. But only from that don't expect your program to work perfectly. There are also serious logic mistakes and with the indentation you have, it's impossible to read the code.